How to prove that there is an infinite number of primes $p$ for which $(p-3)x^{p-3}\equiv 1\pmod p$ has a solution?
I want to prove that there is an infinite number of primes $p$ for which the congruence $(p-3)x^{p-3}\equiv 1\pmod p$ has a solution. Using Dirichlet's theorem, I got that there is an infinite number of primes of the form $p=6k+1$, and because $(1/p)=1$, we get that there is an $x$ with
$x^2\equiv 1\pmod p$ so that $x^{2(3k-1)}\equiv 1\pmod p$, whice gives $x^{p-3}\equiv 1\pmod p$.
How do I proceed?

Why write it this way? This is equivalent to $x^2\equiv -3\pmod p$, which clearly is solvable for infinitely many $p$.

@lulu Can you please show how they are equivalent?

$p-3\equiv -3\pmod p$ and $x^{p-3}\equiv x^px^{-3}\equiv x^{-2}\pmod p$.  And note that $x$ can't be $0$.

$-3x^{p-3}\equiv1\iff-3\equiv x^2$ using Fermat’s little theorem $x^{p-1}\equiv1$

Scaling by $,x^2\not\equiv 0,$ shows $,1\equiv -3x^{p-3}\iff x^2\equiv -3x^{p-1}\equiv -3.,$ But it is easy to show $-3$ is a square mod $p$ for infinitely many $p,,$ e.g. see linked dupes.  Beware that the accepted answer was incorrect.

We can first simplify the congruence equation (assume $p>3$):
$$(p-3)x^{p-3}\equiv -3x^{p-3} \equiv -3 x^{-2} \equiv 1 \Leftrightarrow x^2+3\equiv 0$$
where we have used $x^{p-1}\equiv 1$, as $x$ obviously cannot be $0$.
By Chebotarev's density theorem, $x^2+3$ splits mod $p$ for infinitely many $p$. Or more elementarily, by quadratic reciprocity,
$$\big(\frac{-3}{p}\big)=\big(\frac{-1}{p}\big)\big(\frac{3}{p}\big)=(-1)^{(p-1)/2}(-1)^{(p-1)/2}\big(\frac{p}{3}\big)=\big(\frac{p}{3})$$
Therefore $\big(\frac{-3}{p}\big)=1$ iff $p\equiv 1\mod 3$. By Dirichlet's theorem, there are definitely infinitely many such $p$.

@MSEU $x^{-2}=(x^2)^{-1}$ is the modular multiplicative inverse of $x^2$, not the inverse of $x^2$ as an integer. In other words, ${1, 2, \cdots, p-1}$ form an abelian group through multiplication mod $p$, and $x^{-2}$ is the inverse of $x^2$ relative to the group operation.

Error somewhere since e.g. $,{-}3\equiv 2,$ is nonsquare $\bmod 5.\ \ $

Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see here.
